# HTTP Request/Response class

Tags: php, object-oriented, http, library, framework

I would like to get feedback on this, which are just simple `Response`/`Request` classes.

I tried to keep it simple, so I made two interfaces and two classes:

- RequestInterface.php
- Request.php
- ResponseInterface.php
- Response.php

The `use Foo\Storage\ArrayHandler as access;` is just a class to access and set arrays, so I wouldn't have to use functions like `array_key_exists` all over the place to check for keys, set, and unset arrays.

#### RequestInterface.php

```
namespace Foo\Http;
interface RequestInterface
{
    public function get($key, $default = null);
    public function post($key, $default = null);
    public function server($key, $default = null);
    public function getMethod();
}
```

#### ResponseInterface.php

```
namespace Foo\Http; 
interface ResponseInterface
{
    public function setStatusCode($statusCode);
    public function addHeader($name, $value);
    public function setContentType($contentType);
    public function redirect($url);
}
```

#### Request.php

```
namespace Foo\Http;
use Foo\Storage\ArrayHandler as access; 
class Request implements RequestInterface
{

    protected $get; 
    protected $post;
    protected $files;
    protected $server;
    protected $cookies;


  public function __construct(
         access $get,
         access $post,
         access $files,
         access $server,
         access $cookies
    ) {
        $this->get = $get;
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->cookies = $cookies;
    }


    public function get($key, $defaultValue = null){
      return $this->get->get($key, $defaultValue);
    }

    public function post($key, $defaultValue = null){
        return $this->post->get($key, $defaultValue);
    }

    public function server($key, $defaultValue = null){
        return $this->server->get($key, $defaultValue); 
    }

    public function getMethod(){
        return $this->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD');
    }
}
```

#### Response.php

```
namespace Foo\Http; 

class Response implements ResponseInterface
{

    private $statusCode = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK';
    private $headers = [];

    public function addHeader($name, $value){
        $this->headers[$name][] = $value;
    }

    public function setHeader($name, $value){
        $this->headers[$name] = [
            (string) $value,
        ];
    }

    public function redirect($url){
        $this->setHeader('Location', $url);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's not much to say, these files don't 'do' much. At this point the purpose of these files elude me. As far as OOP goes it seems alright. But, I think there's a bug in `Response.php`, which you call `Request.php`; Each header can have multiple values?

Comment: There is now a PSR recommended standard for the `RequestInterface` and `ResponseInterface`: [composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/http-message) and [original PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at Symfony's [HttpFoundation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html) component.

They've written various Request/Response objects similar to what you're attempting to do and they are extremely well done. Either I'd use them directly(save your own time). Or if this is an exploratory exercise then take a look at their [code base](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation) to see how you can improve on your own solution.

It's not as sexy as writing your own objects, but it'll save you a lot of time and effort in the long run.